# How to download https file in AIX without wget and curl?

Tags: curl, wget, aix, download, https

In an UNIX environment running AIX where I'm a not privileged user (without sudo) if I need to download a file from HTTPS server and there is no wget or curl... How I do it?

Is there any replacement for wget/curl?

Comment: the only change would be s/POST/GET in the corresponding answer.

Comment: thank you for this link. The given solution didn't worked well (script hanged/freezed). But seeking on how to download with perl has _opened my mind_ and I found a solution that I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the given "possibly duplicate" solution didn't worked well as the file has more than 3.9 Gigabytes. But searching on how download files with perl, I found an useful script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669670/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-perl) that worked fine then I edited to receive 2 arguments:

1) the download link

2) the local filename

```
## Using Mechanize
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = $ARGV[0];
my $local_file_name = $ARGV[1];

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
```

Comment: untested, but there's also [LWP::Simple:getstore()](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple#getstore)

Comment: You can also download the file to your workstation and SFTP it to the server.